# Troubleshooting a force feedback wheel with a DC motor that resets when blocked from rotating in a specific direction

Tags: diodes, dc-motor, back-emf

I am troubleshooting a electronic force feedback steering wheel (Fanatec Porsche 911 Turbo S Wheel) that uses a DC motor for force feedback. The wheel restarts every time force feedback is activated, specifically when the motor rotates the wheel to the left (counter-clockwise) and encounters resistance from the user blocking the wheel or rotating the wheel to the right (clockwise). Disconnecting the motor resolves the issue, but eliminates force feedback. Placing a diode between one of the motor terminals and the connector also resolves the issue, but this allows for force feedback from the right side only. I suspect that a faulty diode may be causing back EMF issues. What would be the recommended next steps to diagnose and fix the problem?

I have added a picture of the PCB with the motor connector.
[image: PCB with motor connector (red hexagon)]

Comment: Can you post a schematic please?

Comment: I apologize, but I don't have a schematic for the steering wheel as it is produced by a company called Fanatec and they do not provide access to their schematics.

Comment: Well, that would be my recommended route to resolve the problem.

Comment: A DC motor will draw more current when it is blocked from rotating. But it's probably designed for this, so is it possible that the power supply is too weak?

Comment: Thank you @user253751, this was indeed the problem.